# mysql dump command vs 'waiting for table lock property'

Tags: php, mysql

I usually take backup of my db using MySQL dump same time I observed that my sub domain where i have hosted the application does not load. When I checked the status in PHPmyadmin. It shows an error saying 'waiting for table lock property'. I searched few threads on the same but i'm just not understanding how is it related to my loading of sub domain because i haven't used any db connections or queries in my index page. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't put normal sentence in code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqldump command is locking your table during the process.
Add the option "--single-transaction" in your mysqldump command so the dump process does not lock your table until the dump is completed for the table.
mysqldump --single-transaction ....

Check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction

Comment: Hi, It worked.My application runs as usual while taking back up.Thank you so much.